# Cannot find module "morgan" and but I see morgan exists as dependencies in my package.json file

Tags: node.js, express, npm, morgan

I am trying to open an app with npm start, but keep getting the error message

> **Error: cannot find module 'morgan'**

I looked up some advices on github or stackoverflow, tried these commands:

> npm install morgan
>
> npm install --save morgan
>
> npm link morgan
>
> npm install mongoose-morgan

None of them works. And I do see morgan 1.10.0 in the dependencies of my package.json file.

Anyone knows what's happening?

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this? I have the same issue

Comment: It's still actual

Answer (score 2):

have you tried deleting node_modules and running

> npm install

Answer (score 0):

In my case. Problem with using docker and docker volume. After I installed morgan .dockerignore has node_modules I will delete docker volume and rebuild docker container.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try :

- **npm link morgan**
- npm link morgan is used to create a symbolic link between a globally installed "morgan" package and a local project.